# Not getting variable values in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKUmE.jpg)

Trying to fetch project name ,build number and build status for job..which are jenkins environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Please see below example by which you can access the jenkins environmental variables and get the values :

```
println ("Job name is : ${JOB_BASE_NAME}")
println ("Job number is : ${BUILD_ID}")
println ("Build status is :  ${currentBuild.currentResult}")
```

Comment: @shiva shankar S.D does this work for you